# Laravel PHP 8.1 on GCP APP engine deploying error

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-php

I use cloud build trigger to build my first APP Engine, but I keep receiving following message.

"There is no PHP runtime version specified in composer.json, or
we don't support the version you specified. Google App Engine
uses the latest 7.3.x version."

I already tried following settings but still don't work.

composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^8.1",
```

In app.yalm:

```
runtime: php81
```

In cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
        - '-c'
        - |
          gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 3600 \
          && gcloud app deploy -q --promote -v=$BUILD_ID \
          --project=$PROJECT_ID

timeout: '3600s'
```

And I tried following commend:

```
composer require php 8.1.*

composer clearcache

composer update
```

Comment: I have not worked on google cloud still now. But according to your php error I guess your engine is not compatible for working with php 8.1; Have you any configuration or settings file where you can define value for php version to build?

Comment: GCP official site says PHP8.1 is ok. I followed official document but still don't work. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime#choosing_a_php_version)

> By default, the PHP runtime uses PHP 7.3, but you should explicitly declare your PHP version in the composer.json file to prevent your application from being automatically upgraded when a new version of PHP becomes available. The PHP version 7.2.* is also supported.
>
> ```
> {
>     "require": {
>         "php": "7.3.*"
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Note :When you specify the PHP version, use the format MAJOR.MINOR.*
> and do not specify the release version. The PHP runtime is regularly
> updated to the latest release version and only supports one release
> version at a time, so specifying a release version can cause an error.

Comment: GCP [official site](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/runtime) says PHP8.1 is supported. I tried  `"php": "8.1.*"`  but still got same error message.

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/runtime#runtime_version:~:text=Note%3A%20If%20you%20have%20a%20required%20PHP%20version%20specified%20in%20your%20composer.json%20file%2C%20you%20will%20have%20to%20remove%20the%20element%20for%20a%20successful%20deployment.)This element `runtime` needs to be removed from app.yaml if it is specified in composer.json. Also confirm you are using standard envirionment

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found out that I'm using flexible environment but not standard environment.

Answer (score 0):

Version handling in buildpack running behind the scene is inconsistent. Issue is discussed here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/issues/336

In general `"php": "^8.1.*"` should work.

If you are dealing with Laravel + App Engine you can check  https://github.com/firevel/firevel